# Azure AD B2C: Custom IDP

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

While creating a custom IDP for my Azure AD B2C service I get the following error:

[image]
I did validate the JSON content for the JWKS endpoint on an online json lint and it validated it fine. Is there any specific expected format of the JSON content?

Answer (score 0):

You should be providing the well known OIDC endpoint. The JWKS URI is referenced from within the well known OIDC endpoint.

Comment: You are correct. This JWKS URI error was received when the openid-configuration endpoint(e.g.: https://myserver.com/.well-known/openid-configuration) was provided in the Metadata url field.

Comment: All of these are public endpoints, you should post it so we can help you further.